# Checking if email already exists in MySQLdb utilizing python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

My goal is to check if an e-mail already exists in the mysql database. I am pulling the information into the variable from a webform (string). I currently have the following code:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","username","password","databasename")
cursor = db.cursor()
if cursor.execute("select count(*) from registrants where email = " + "'"emailvar"'") == 0:
    print "it doesn't exist"
```

When I attempt to access the page I get an internal server error. I narrowed down the error to the "'"emailvar"'", and the code works fine, but e-mails have "@" and "." which cause SQL syntax errors. I attempt to escape them utilizing "'" "'" opening and closing parenthesis, but it does not work and crashes the web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
query = 'select count(*) from registrants where email=%s'
cursor.execute(query, emailvar)
if next(cursor, None) is None:
    # whatever
```

But would look at `.fetchone()` which should work, and also `EXISTS` in SQL (whereby it should have a unique constraint and let the DB work it out) and return a boolean-esque empty result.

Comment: I get the error: 

builtin next = <built-in function next>, cursor = <MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object>, builtin None = None

<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Cursor object is not an iterator
      args = ('Cursor object is not an iterator',)
      message = 'Cursor object is not an iterator'

Comment: @MichaelRocca oh - I forgot it works that way - try `fetchone` instead on the cursor object

Comment: @JonClements: I corrected the code. I think you might want to pad the answer out with something about prepared statements too.

Comment: @KeithGaughan Thank you - however, please feel free to offer your own answer - I'm rolling this back so that things stay in order - no offense intended (but your edit is a complete change to my original intention)

Comment: No problem. I don't really feel like answering it myself as, except for the whole result fetching thing, your answer's just fine.